# Solving a system of equations using matrix form

Tags: equation-solving

Please bear with me as I am a beginner at Mathematica.

In the following system, all variables on the right hand side are known, except for `w1`, `w2` and `w3`, for which we are trying to solve. 
[image]

I am trying to solve this system in Mathematica, but I am not sure where to start. Also, in my real example, the system is composed of 10 equations instead of three: we are trying to solve for `w1`, `w2` and `w3` where `FA = FB = FC = FD =  .... = Fj`.

Please let me know if the explanation is a bit confusing, and I will try to explain better! Thanks!

Comment: You will have to post actual Mathematica code for readers to have much chance of offering assistance.

Comment: Sure, I will try doing that soon. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the numerator results in scalar quantity (1x3.3x3.3.1=1x1). you can not equate vector quantity {FA,FB,FC} with scalar quantity.

Comment: @Algohi Yes you are right. There is a typo.. I will fix this

Comment: @Algohi Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have corrected it. Please refer to my updated post!

Comment: @Mariam You NEED to provide the actual code, not an image.

Comment: @Öskå I understand. However, I mentioned in my post that my knowledge of Mathematica is very basic/restricted, hence not being able to provide code.. My intention with this post is to get some help implementing this problem in Mathematica.

Comment: @Mariam Well, if you know how to type, how to create a matrix you should be able to provide a code.

Comment: Just type out the equation(s) in plain ascii. I doubt anyone will want to enter, from scratch, what you've shown in an image. But readers might be willing to convert actual ascii equations, that can be cut and pasted, into proper Mathematica syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will show you how to write the equations. Execute each step to see the result

```
sigma = Thread[Subscript[σ, {A, B, C}]]

(cov = Outer[Times, sigma, sigma] /.
    Subscript[σ, x_] * Subscript[σ, y_] :>
     Subscript[σ, x] * Subscript[σ, y]  * 
      Subscript[ρ, ToString[x] <> ToString[y]]) // MatrixForm

weights = Thread[Subscript[w, Range[3]]]

(m = Table[Subscript[β, i]^j, 
       {j, {A, B, C}}, {i, 3}].weights) //
 MatrixForm

denom = (Total[
      Table[Subscript[w, n]*Subscript[σ, n], {n, 3}]]^2 //
    Expand) /. 
  Subscript[σ, x_] * Subscript[σ, y_] :>
   Subscript[σ, x] * Subscript[σ, y]  * 
    Subscript[ρ, Sequence[x, y]]

f = Thread[Subscript[F, {A, B, C}]]

eqns = Thread[f == cov.m/denom];

constraints = {Total[weights] == 1, Equal @@ (m.f)}

sol = Solve[Join[eqns, constraints], weights]
```

This last statement will not be solved in any reasonable amount of time (ever?). However, if the "known" values are given numeric values it might be doable.

```
sol = With[{***"assign numeric values here"***}, 
  Solve[Join[eqns, constraints], weights]]
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this!

Comment: Note with a little manipulation the `denom` quantity can be eliminated from the system. If you do that `Solve` will have an easier time of it. (Still highly unlikely to get a symbolic solution, but given all the symmetry it is worth a shot. )

Comment: Actually all the known values have a numerical value assigned to them, so it is definitely solvable!

Answer (score 1):

This is simple way of writing the equations

Though no solution is found.

[image]

if you want to use the symbols as seen the image you can use the Mathematica Palettes which you can find at the main menu.

[image]